# multiline graphviz node with math mode

Tags: graphviz, dot2tex

I have a node which represents a multiline label in math mode. However, I failed to include the newline symbol `\n` into the node label. Here is my try

```
\begin{dot2tex}[neato,scale=.5,options=-t math]
digraph G
{
c[shape=none,label="x_1",pos="1,.25!"];
d[label="D",pos=".5,-1.6!"];


}
\end{dot2tex}
```

How can I add newline for the node `c`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/dot2tex-users/nAQ2SwRxH6s/2KMDjwF5JNcJ) by using `matrix` package from `tikz`

```
\begin{dot2tex}[neato,scale=.8,options=-t math]
digraph G
{
c[shape=none,texlbl="$
\begin{matrix}
x_1
\\ x_2
\end{matrix}$"
,pos="1,-1.2!"];

}
\end{dot2tex}
```

will add node with two lines $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Answer (score 1):

From the [dot2tex documentation page](http://www.fauskes.net/code/dot2tex/documentation/):

> The `\` character needs to be escaped with `\\` if used in the `label` attribute.

Therefore, `label="first line\\\\second line"` (four backslashes) should result in a latex newline sequence (can't test it though).

Comment: thanks but that did not work for me. I found the answer in adding matrix